# How to render the items from the views to the template?

Tags: python, django, web

I am a beginner in django and  I have encountered a problem here . My models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class course_name(models.Model):
    faculty_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.faculty_name


class subject(models.Model):
    subject_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    faculty_names=models.ForeignKey(course_name,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_name

class lectures(models.Model):
    lecture_topic=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lecture_number=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    subjects=models.ForeignKey(subject,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.lecture_topic


class lecture_dets(models.Model):
    lecture_pdfs=models.FileField(upload_to='documents',null=True)
    lecture_vids=models.FileField(upload_to='videos',null=True)
    lecture_notes=models.FileField(upload_to='notes',null=True)
    lecture_name=models.ForeignKey(lectures,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.lecture_name}'
```

also my views.py

```
def Lectures(request,lecture_number):
        Lectures = lectures.objects.filter(lecture_number=lecture_number)
        context={"lectures":Lectures}
        return render(request,'home/lectures.html',context)
```

I want to render the views in my templates and I am not being able to use lecture_number in the template lectures.html. I think there is default id field but don't know how to begin ??

Comment: You've not added `lecture_number` to your context. Only keys in the context are available in the template

Comment: whats your scenario?  how do you want to lecture to render in your template?

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `"lecture_number"` along with `"lectures"` in the the context:

```
context={"lectures":Lectures, "lecture_number": lecture_number}
return render(request,'home/lectures.html',context)
```

And render it in template:

```
{{ lecture_number }}
```